# Log discrepancy of a toric exceptional divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $X$ be a toric singularity determined by a single cone. By taking a partition of the cone we may get a toric resolution of $X$.

Question: How can we compute the log discrepancies of the exceptional divisors using the combinatorial data?

For example, let $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the cone generated by $(0,1)$ and $(n,1)$, and $X$ the corresponding toric variety. Let $C_i$ be the cone generated by $(i-1,1), (i,1)$ for $1\le i \le n$, and $\rho_i$ be the ray of $(i,1)$. We denote by $\Delta$ the fan generated by those cones $C_i$, and $Y$ the toric variety determined by $\Delta$, and $D_i\subseteq Y$ the toric divisor corresponding to $\rho_i$. Then the induced morphism $Y\to X$ is a toric resolution of $X$. How can we compute the log discrepancies $A_X(D_i)$?

Thanks very much for your answer!